# Lotus Notes @Command([MailForward]) Command issue

Tags: lotus-notes

Someone please let me know what exactly **@Command([MailForward])** command does?

In my organization, I take care of several existing notes based applications. Here, one of the users is getting error message when clicks on 'Email Quote' button in one of the applications. The button contains the formula **'@Command([MailForward])'**. As the user clicks on the button, he gets following error:

[image]

Here in the organization, all the users use **'Outlook/Exchange'** for emails, and notes emailing is not enabled. Other users of the application are able to click the button and send quotation via mail. The issue is with this specific user only.

I think there is some configuration settings in location entry or person document (names.nsf) that I am missing. Please guide me.

Thanks

Romil Handoo

Answer (score 1):

@Command([MailForward]) is a command that takes the current Notes document that you are looking at and attempts to create a new email with that document included in the body. This is similar to what you see when you forward an email in Outlook.

Since you aren't using Notes for your mail, this action will not work. The error message you are receiving is there because the current user doesn't have a Lotus Notes mail file configured.